# How to update a child entity in @OnetoMany relationship in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent class:

```
@Entity(name = "Master")
@Table(name = "master")
public class Master {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name") 
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "master", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
    List<AdditionalAttribute> additionalAttributes = new ArrayList<>();


    public void addAttributes(AdditionalAttribute attribute) {
        additionalAttributes.add(attribute);
        attribute.setFindings(this);
    }

    public void removeAttributes(AdditionalAttribute attribute) {
        additionalAttributes.remove(attribute);
        attribute.setFindings(null);
    }
}
```

And the child class:

```
@Entity(name = "additional_attribute")
public class AdditionalAttribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    private String attributeName;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String attributeValue;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "master_id")
    private Master master;

}
```

Now let's say I already have inserted data in both the tables like:

```
  Master
 ================
 id.      name
 1.       xyz

 AdditionalAttribute
======================================================
 id.     attributeName.   attributeValue.    master_id
 1         Acme               test               1
 2.        loreal             red                1
```

Now given the `master_id`, how do I update the `attributeValue` in the `AdditionalAttribute` table for that id??

What I have done is:

1. Get the list of `additionalAttributes` from the master entity (the one we got from session)
2. Iterate over the list and get each `AdditionAttribute` object.
3. Set the new value to the object.

Is it a good way of updating? Do we have any better approach?

Comment: What if updating entities simply with an SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your application would want to update a single AdditionalAttribute record, I would like to suggest that you search from the AdditionalAttribute side eg, if you are using JPARepository you can use findByMaster(Long masterId) rather than searching from the MasterRepository and do the iterations.